# Best Pen for Maths?

Tags: paper, pens, ink

I'm a maths undergrad and I am looking for a very smooth pen that's good for speed writing symbols and iterations (like a pencil?).

Uniball Air Micro and Elite Vision both seem to have some good reviews.

Is the Elite Vision similar to Pilot V5/V7 in terms of smoothness? (I personally find it quite difficult to write smoothly with V5/V7 so not a big fan of that).

Which one would be the better choice or any other recommendation?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  I'm not sure how answerable this question is as written.  There isn't really a pen ideally suited specifically for math and symbols.  The smoothness and feedback of the pen on the paper are mostly a matter of personal preference.  A big factor is how small you write so how thin a line is required.  The pressure you use and the paper also play a big role.  The question will attract lists of pens people like for their own reason, basically a preference poll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer, because its based mostly off of personal preference. Out of those two pens, I personally prefer the Elite Vision, because the Air micro is sort of like a fine liner tip, and doesn't glide as easily. If I could choose any pens, my first pick would be the Pilot V Ball RT Extra Fine. They're pretty cheap, and they glide across the paper. They also require very little pressure, so that helps prevent hand cramps. My second choice would be the Pilot Varsity. Its a disposable fountain pen that is amazing. They have a nice line, but depending on the paper you use, the might bleed a little. 3rd choice is the Lamy AL-star Rollerball. Its a little more pricey, around $35, but its refillable and highly durable. Its a nice grip and weight, and a good line too. But overall, the Pilot V Ball Extra Fine would most likely be the best.